# Complex shapes in Box2D with LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, physics, shapes

I am experimenting with `box2d` physics in my Java libgdx project. I want to draw a shape with the finger/mouse and convert it to a dynamic body. I tried using a chain shape but that did not work. The object falls down, but it does not rotate, when hitting something. Afaik the problem is, that the object has no mass, because it is only a line. How could I do this differently?

Answer (score 0):

For `ChainShape` you have to set MassData manually - it needs to has `inertia` defined:

```
    MassData m = new MassData();

    m.center.set(0, 0);
    m.I = 100; //example value
    body.setMassData(m);
```

You can read more about Moment of inertia on [Wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)

Comment: That does not change anything. The object still stays in the same rotation, even when touching the ground with only one side...